# Add Hyperlink to all first column data using Bash script

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have log files which I am filtering to get some output like

```
WI_1_test  pass
WI_2_test fail
WI_3_test pass
```

I want to make all the data on the first column to have a hyperlink which is clickable...basically pointing to a url which is unique for each test.

with bash.

more explanation!
                                                                                                                                                                                     I have a log file of test results and i want to prepare a report from the messy log. i am using awk to filter to the above      WI_1_test  pass ..etc. and below is my code.

```
awk '/rtest.rosunit-rtest/' logfilefromjenkins.txt | sed 's/^.*\(WI\).\([0-9]*\)..\([a-Z]*\).*/\1-\2,\3/g'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$1="http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id="$1'|sort  > testreport.csv    .
```

like so =>
my current result after i run the code above is outputting  only the different links on the first column.

```
http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_1_test , pass

http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_2_test , fail
```

meanwhile my end goal is to have all the data as shown above on the first column pointing to unique urls, such that when i export a pdf report. just by clicking on any of the test on the first column the user can be redirected to the test url on the system.

This is my expectation for all column 1 data :

[WI_1_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_1_test) , pass

[WI_2_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_2_test) , fail

Answer (score 0):

it's not pretty but you can modify your awk expression like this

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$1="["$1"](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id="$1")"'
```

output should then look like this

```
[WI_1_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_1_test) , pass

[WI_2_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_2_test) , fail
```

which is markdown syntax for clickable links

you should also be able do this in sed directly.

perhaps like this

```
sed 's/^.*\(WI\).\([0-9]*\)..\([a-Z]*\).*/[\1-\2](http:\/\/...=\1-\2),\3/g'
```

maybe you need to escape the brackets and parens. i cannot test because i do not have your input data. also i do not fully understand your sed expression because there should be a dash in the output but there is none in your example output.